# Related video algorithm MySql using genre

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've looked around for info on an efficient 'related videos' algorithm but i'm struggling to get well ordered, accurate results

I get given the 'genre' as a pipe-delimited string. eg: |Action|Sci-Fi|Thriller|

```
$genre = explode("|", $row['genre']);

if (count($genre) == 3) {
    $sql = "SELECT title FROM `movie` WHERE genre LIKE '%$genre[1]%' LIMIT 0,8";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT title FROM `movie` WHERE (genre LIKE '%$genre[1]%' AND genre LIKE '%$genre[2]%') UNION SELECT title FROM `movie` WHERE (genre LIKE '%$genre[1]%' OR genre LIKE '%$genre[2]%') LIMIT 0,10";
}
$related = mysql_query($sql);
```

Then I basically explode it and do a manual, inefficient search for genre matches depending on genre count. The results are poor and returns anything that is semi related.

This code makes me want to gag! It works but I hate it and I know its uber lame. Any tips to improve the SQL and getting richer results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the mappings of genres to movies into a new table `movie_genres` with columns `movie` and `genre`.

This allows you to do this:

```
$genres = explode('|', trim($row['genre'], '|'));
$sql = "SELECT `movie`, COUNT(*) AS hits
        FROM `movie_genres`
        WHERE `genre` IN ('" . join("', '", $genres) . "')
        GROUP BY `movie`
        ORDER BY `hits` DESC
        LIMIT 8";
```

You have to make sure to prevent SQL injection, though.

The extra table is also a good idea, because your database schema is not normalized. Especially Chris Date's fourth condition of the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) is violated:

> Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one value from the applicable domain (and nothing else).

Comment: Do I have to worry about SQL injection if it's a nightly CronJob?

Comment: When you construct an SQL statement from variables, you have to make sure that the statement is *syntactically* correct and behaves *semantically* as you intend it to; always. When you have genres like `jazz`, `blues`, `rock`, this is not a problem. But a genre `rock'n'roll` will ruin the query syntax. Even worse, an attacker might keep the syntax intact, but change the semantics of the query. It depends on where `$row['genre']` comes from.